# Tick and label for every xAxis Unit in Highcharts Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, coffeescript

I have a  chart like the one in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h9Bqj/

[image: Highcharts]
As shown in the image there is no tick for "3" and "5" on the xAxis as well as no label. I am not able to figure out how to show a tick for every xAxis.

The `[...]
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            step: 1
        },
        tickInterval: 1
    }`
 options did not work for me.

How would I get a tick and a label for every increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set tickInterval as 1, as you have, and add `pointInterval` as 1.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

http://jsfiddle.net/h9Bqj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out by myself.

Setting pointRange via `plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    pointRange: 1
                }
            },` in the options or in the series does the trick.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DZbyp/1/